# How to extract certain directories of a zip file in SH?

Tags: sh, unzip

So, I am making a program to extract the certain files/folders needed to make a program that extracts certain parts of a zip file (using the unzip command in sh).

Here is what I want to happen:
Instead of the unzip command only extracting the whole zip file, I want it to extract a certain directory (lets say assets/minecraft/textures) instead of the whole zip file. Any way I can do this?

Here is my command so far: `unzip textures.zip`

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the unzip command already supports this option... Just take a look at manpages

[unzip(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip)

It accepts regular expressions also.

For example:

```
unzip textures.zip folder1 folder2 ... folderN
```

Comment: Too broad. I need the option for it (the command) and I seem to cant find where the option is.

Comment: Actually, is just pass the folders as arguments... (added an example to the answer)